# «В умат» — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно, жаргон

В художественной прозе, которую редактирую, встретила выражение **в умат**.
Как написать? У автора именно так.

Answer (score 1):

Выражения, не фиксирующиеся словарями, не могут иметь нормативного написания. Это естественно.
Но по аналогии с выражениями "в угоду", "в укор" и т. д. — раздельно. "Умат" здесь претендует на "звание" самостоятельного слова.
Есть, правда, "вусмерть", но здесь "усмерть" не самостоятельное слово, а окказиональное образование от "умирать"+"смерть".

Comment: @Третийглаз Извините, если уж Вы редактируете ответ, то тогда просматривайте и исправляйте весь текст. Здесь, например: _Выражение, не фиксирующиеся словарями, не могут..._ Плюс отсутствие запятой перед "но". Мне кажется, что просто изменять дефисик на тире — нет смысла. Вы заполонили весь сайт такими псевдоправками. Еще раз извините.

Answer (score 0):

Выражение есть в большом словаре русских поговорок:
[УМАТ](http://www.endic.ru/thief/Umat-6229.html)
**В умат (в умате)**
1. *Разг.* В состоянии сильного алкогольного опьянения.
2. *Жарг. мол.* В состоянии восторга, восхищения.
**Не в умат** *кому что. Жарг. мол. Неодобр.* Неприятно, скверно.

Думаю, что здесь работает вот это правило.
Раздельно пишутся наречия, образованные из сочетаний существительных с предлогами, если предлог оканчивается на согласную, а существительное начинается с гласной:
*в обмен, в обрез, в обхват, в убыток, в упор.*
[Раздельное написание наречий и наречных сочетаний](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.38)

В сборнике "[Вопросы культуры речи](https://books.google.ee/books?id=5uNTDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA124&lpg=PA124&dq=%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82:%20%D0%B2%20%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%20%D0%B2%20%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=Hz9W_RZnc5&sig=ACfU3U1BL6OEqxCS65AHhOwD5KTP2ymSmg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwipxsr_hZblAhXhsosKHZVyDmsQ6AEwCXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%3A%20%D0%B2%20%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%20%D0%B2%20%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5&f=false)" (выпуск XI) есть полный список сочетаний предлогов с существительными. **В умат** и **в умате** там присутствуют.